# Perl: Multiple ='s signs in one line (list and scalar context confusion)

Tags: perl

I saw this line from a tutorial on Perl:

```
$ret = (($i, $j, $k)=(5,6,8,9)); # 4
```

I'm not familiar with the format to have multiple ='s signs in one line. From what I read it has something to do with context.

It seems strange to me to wrap `($i, $j, $k)=(5,6,8,9)` with another pair of parentheses, but I'll take it as interpreting the wrapped text in list context.

But then, why is the following different? Doesn't the `= () =` mean the same thing? Why does the assignment take place before the list context does?

```
$ret = () = ($i, $j, $k)=(5,6,8,9); # 3
```

and yet the following is 4 again?

```
$ret = ($i, $j, $k)=(5,6,8,9); # 4
```

Answer (score 3):

A common misconception is that the following assigns `a` to `b`:

b = a = 3

But you wouldn't expect the following to assign `a` to `b`, right?

b = a + 3

You have to look at what `=` evaluates to (returns).

As per [Mini-Tutorial: Scalar vs List Assignment Operator](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=790129),

- A list assignment in list context evaluates to the scalars returned by its LHS as lvalues.
- A list assignment in scalar context evaluates to the number of scalars returned by its RHS.

---

Assignments have right-to-left associativity, so

```
 $ret = () = ($i, $j, $k) = (5, 6, 8, 9);
```

means

```
       3       2                1
  $ret = ( ()  = ( ($i, $j, $k) = (5, 6, 8, 9) ));
```

1. The first assignment operator is a list assignment in list context. It evaluates to the scalars returned by its LHS as lvalues (`$i, $j, $k`).
2. The second assignment operator is a list assignment in scalar context. It evaluates to the number of scalars returned by its RHS (`3`).
3. The third assignment operator assigns this to `$ret`.

---

Similarly

```
 $ret = ($i, $j, $k) = (5, 6, 8, 9);
```

means

```
      2                1
 $ret = ( ($i, $j, $k) = (5, 6, 8, 9) );
```

1. The second assignment operator is a list assignment in scalar context. It evaluates to the number of scalars returned by its RHS (4).
2. The second assignment operator assigns this to `$ret`.

Comment: Referring to `$ret = ( ()  = ( ($i, $j, $k) = (5, 6, 8, 9) ));`, I don't understand why #2 is a "list assignment in scalar context", particularly why it's in scalar context. `() = ($i, $j, $k)`. Both the lhs and rhs here look like lists.

Comment: Because #3 is a scalar assignment, and the scalar assignment imposes a scalar context on its arguments (LHS = `$ret`, RHS = #2)